# Thread synchronizing - almost same expressions but different result

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized

```
public class MythreadM {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Msg m = new Msg();
        Mythread thread1 = new Mythread(m);
        thread1.start();
        
        Mythread thread2 = new Mythread(m);
        thread2.start();
        
        Mythread thread3 = new Mythread(m);
        thread3.start();
    }

}
class Mythread extends Thread
{
    private Msg m;
    
    Mythread(Msg m)
    {
        this.m = m;
    }
    public void run() 
    {
        System.out.println(getName()+"start");
        for(int i=0; i<300; i++)
        {
            processMsg(i);
        }
    }
    synchronized void processMsg(int i) // here starts question.
    {
//      synchronized(m)
        {
            m.write(getName()+" message "+i);
            try {
                sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            m.print();
        }   
    }
    
}

class Msg
{
    String str = "def message";
    
    void print()
    {
        System.out.println(str+" "+System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
    void write(String str)
    {
        this.str = str;
    }
    
}
```

Full code above-----------------

and following 3 codes with almost same expressions.

<< code 1 >> : synchronized(m) {}

```
    void processMsg(int i)
    {
        synchronized(m)
        {
            m.write(getName()+" message "+i);
            try {
                sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            m.print();
        }   
    }
```

<< code 2 >> : synchronized void processMsg(int i)

```
    synchronized void processMsg(int i)
    {

        {
            m.write(getName()+" message "+i);
            try {
                sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            m.print();
        }   
    }
```

It looks these codes mean same just with different expressions but acts different.
< code 2 > is not synchronized, prints non-synchronized results.
Why is this happening?
And what's the **purpose** of the `sleep(1);` ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the differences you are observing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this is example code to demonstrate that when synchronize on an object common to all threads (m), only one thread at a time can use it, as opposed to when you synchronize a method in the thread, which doesn't do anything because each thread is getting it's own lock.

To your second question, the meaning of sleep(1) is that the current thread should wait for *at least* 1 millisecond before proceeding.

Finally, in my experience, when you have several threads that are after the same resource (especially a (Print)stream like System.out) that the best way to solve this is to have a message queue to ynchronize the messages going out.

Comment: "when you synchronize a method in the thread, which doesn't do anything because each thread is getting it's own lock.", i don't get this, as i know 'synchronizing a method 'in the thread like `synchronized void processMsg(int i)`, only one thread can use this method and other threads should wait until it finishes using.

Comment: @bbiot426 Re: 'only one thread can use...' Let me try to clarify your understanding. All objects (and classes, because they are also Class objects) in Java have a monitor lock. Adding synchronized in a method definition means "Get this object's lock and don't release it until the end of the method". So while a thread is in a synchronized method, no other thread process a synchronized method on the object (they need to wait for the object's lock to be released) but the trick here is that if you synchronize the methods in the threads, it won't change anything because each get's it's own lock

Comment: @markspace Do you mean <code 1> don't work neither? i'm still confused, wondering why <code 1> works well (synchronized). @controlaltdel "Get this object's lock" means `m.write()` in method is getting m's lock?  you didn't mean method is object too right?

Comment: @markspace Why do you think <code 1> wouldn't work (assuming that synchronized(m) was uncommented)?

Comment: Ah, never mind, I completely missed that `m` was being passed in and was not (entirely) private.